# Show that the function f does not have limit at $x = 0:$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

The function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-1 & x\leq 0\\ 
1 &  x>0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that the function f does not have limit at $x = 0:$

Here clearly left limit and right limit  exist but not equal  but how to prove this

Comment: The left limit and right limit exist, but they are  not equal to each other. What do you mean by "definition sequential limit"?

Answer (score 3):

This comes from the definition of the left limit and right limit. If these two limits exist, then the function has the limit in this point. Now consider that they are not equal to each other:
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-1\neq1=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$$
to prove $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-1$ with definition, we notice that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $\delta=1$ such that for $-\delta<x<0$,
$$|f(x)-(-1)|=|-1-(-1)|=0<\varepsilon$$
holds for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: @nosrati....that's I know but how to prove mathematically..sorry if I said anything wrong

Comment: clearly for all $x$ less than $0$ then points of the range are $-1$, then when it tends to $0^-$ the function get the value $-1$.

Comment: @CrackTheSolution I don't understand what is unclear to you. Do you want to prove that the limit does not exist if the left limit is different than the right limit?

Comment: @Andrei,,,yeah I want to prove

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists, it is either $1$, $-1$ or some other value. The $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit says that a function has a limit $L$ at $x_0$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ exists a value $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|\le\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|\lt \varepsilon$.

If you choose for example $\varepsilon=1/2$ it means that exists a $\delta$ such that if $|x-0|=|x|\lt\delta$ you get $|f(x)-L|\lt 1/2$. And this has to hold for **every** $|x|\lt \delta$. We can then choose $x_+>0$ and $x_-<0$ and the result should be true. So we have $|f(x_-)-L|\lt 1/2$ and $|f(x_+)-L|\lt 1/2$. Or we can write these as $|-1-L|\lt 1/2$ and $|1-L|\lt 1/2$. The first inequality says $-3/2\lt L\lt -1/2$, the second says $1/2\lt L\lt 3/2$. Obviously the limit cannot be negative and positive at the same time, so the limit does not exists.